# Ontology comparison in owlapi

Tags: ontology, owl-api

I am using OWLAPI for a project, and I need to compare two ontologies for differences between them.  This would ignore blank nodes so that, for instance, I can determine whether the same OWL restrictions are in both ontologies.  Not only do I need to know whether there are differences, but I need to find out what those differences are.  does such functionality exist in the OWLAPI, oz is there a relatively simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality between anonymous class expressions is not based on the blank node ids - anonymous class expressions only have blank nodes in the textual output, in memory the ids are ignored. So checking if an axiom exists in an ontology will by default match expressions correctly for your diff.

This is not true for individuals - anonymous individuals will not be found to be the same across ontologies, and this is by specs. An anonymous individual in one ontology cannot be found in another, because the anonymous individual ids are scoped to the containing ontology.

Note: the unit tests for OWLAPI have to carry out a very similar task, to verify that an ontology can be parsed, written and parsed again without change (i.e., roundtripped between input syntax and output syntax), so there is code that you can look at to take inspiration. See [TestBase.java - equal() method](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version5/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/api/test/baseclasses/TestBase.java) for more details. This includes code to deal with different ids for anonymous individuals.

Comment: In comparing ontologies, I understand that anonymous individuals have no id (so internal ids are insignificant here).  So my intention would be to compare the structure of anonymous nodes.  For instance, a restriction in the context of it's named subclass: given a named subclass that appears in both ontologies, in each ontology is the class a subclass of a restriction whereby the restriction is the subject of the same triples (property and object) in both cases.  That is what I need to determine.

Comment: In your case the subclass axioms are meant to be .equals() to each other, so you can take an axiom from the first ontology and check if the second ontology contains it.

Comment: @Ignazio what about axioms that are not explicitly contained, but can be inferred (using a reasoner). I.e., is there such a functionality to get the logical difference between two ontologies, as in the CEX3 library (https://github.com/michel-ludwig/cex3)?

Comment: Owl api does not have functionalities to do this out of the box. You could use inference generators to create explicit axioms, and then apply the method suggested above, but a reasoner with this function would be a better choice.